# Watch elements of simple array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, watch

Vue dont see changes in simple array items.

I am learning Vue.js and have problem with watcher.
Namely i am trying to watch changes in array, and change one data value.
Every time i add a new item and change or delete an existing item, I want to change the value.

```
data() {
    return {
        change: false,
        array: ['one','two','three','four']
    }
},
watch:{
    array:{
        deep:true,
        handler(){
            this.change = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Vue just see when array length is changed but not particular element.

Comment: How are you changing the array? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Answer (score 0):

You can watch nested values in an `object` as shown in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) use a *dot-like-string* notation.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    e: {
      f: {
        g: 5
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // watch vm.e.f's value: {g: 5}
    'e.f': function (val, oldVal) { /* ... */ }
  }
})
```

To my knowledge you **CANNOT** do this with arrays (i.e. `array[0]`) because the reference my shift or be removed. I think the best way to do what you want is to compare the `newValue` and `oldValue` in the watcher [handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html?#Watchers) function if the whole array changes.

```
// from vuejs docs
watch: {
  // whenever question changes, this function will run
  question: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
    this.answer = 'Waiting for you to stop typing...'
    this.debouncedGetAnswer()
  }
},
```